# Achieve CI with WSO2 API cloud

Tags: jenkins, wso2, continuous-integration, wso2-cloud

I am new to WSO2 altogether and was wondering is there a way to have CI integrated with the WSO2 API Cloud? I know it is possible to do so with the Integration cloud but can the same be done with API cloud ?